# Date stored in DB is in diffrent form causing issues

Tags: java, date, simpledateformat

I am trying to retrieve records from DB which match the passed date.
Passed date is as Wed Jul 16 05:40:07 IST 2014
Value in DB is 7/16/2014 5:40:07.000 PM
Though both dates are same format is different.
This causes my query to return zero results.
Following is my code

```
SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");
    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss",Locale.US);
    date = dateFormat.parse(simpleDateFormat.format(date));

    Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
    List<BuildAnalysisData> alBuildAnalysisData =  new ArrayList<BuildAnalysisData>();
    Query query = session.createQuery(
            "from BuildAnalysisData BuildAnalysisData_Dummy where "
            + "BuildAnalysisData_Dummy.buildDate=:buildDate and BuildAnalysisData_Dummy.projectId=:projectId");

    query.setDate("buildDate", date);
    query.setInteger("projectId", projectId);

    alBuildAnalysisData = query.list();

    //numberOfMissingBuilds = (Integer) query.uniqueResult();
    session.close();
```

In above code query.list() is coming as blank.
Could you please let me know what is going wrong?

Comment: Your passed value is a.m whereas your DB value is p.m

Comment: What's the purpose of first converting `date` to a `String` and then back to a `Date`? At best you will get back the same date but it can also be changed.

Comment: Your date format should match with the value in DB. you are passing the `Date` object as a param. 'Date' object doesn't hold the date format. you can pass `simpleDateFormat.format(date)` as a param within the method `setString` instead of `setDate` Hibernate will handle the data type itself.

Comment: I did that to match the format in DB. But it does not seem to be working.

Comment: Like Java, the value of a Date in a DB should not have any formatting

Comment: Your passed value is **a.m** whereas your DB value is **p.m**

Comment: Hi Umais Gillani, the trck you suggested worked for me thanks a lot